# Why does T reduce(T, BinaryOperator) disallow static method references but reduce(U, BiFunction, BinaryOperator) allows?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There are 2 and 3 arg version of `reduce` in the stream API defined below

```
T reduce(T identity,
         BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)
```

and

```
<U> U reduce(U identity,
             BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
             BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

I'm trying to count the number of words in a sentence with stream/parallel stream and have the following class with the accumulator and combiner

```
class WordCounter {
    private final int counter;
    private final boolean lastSpace;

    // constructor skipped

    public WordCounter accumulate(Character c) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            return lastSpace ?
                    this :
                    new WordCounter(counter, true);
        } else {
            return lastSpace ?
                    new WordCounter(counter + 1, false) :
                    this;
        }
    }

    public WordCounter combine(WordCounter wordCounter) {
        return new WordCounter(counter + wordCounter.counter, wordCounter.lastSpace);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to this test this in the main method with the version of reduce

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String SENTENCE = "please help";

        Stream<Character> stream = IntStream
                .range(0, SENTENCE.length())
                .mapToObj(SENTENCE::charAt);

        int count2 = stream.reduce(new WordCounter(0, true),
                WordCounter::accumulate
        ).getCounter();
}
```

When I try the above,the compiler complains as I'm using non-static `WordCounter::accumulate` from static main

However, within the same static main, the below works

```
int count1 = stream.reduce(new WordCounter(0, true),
                WordCounter::accumulate,
                WordCounter::combine
        ).getCounter();
```

Comment: Is this really the error message you get? The types do not match, `WordCounter::accumulate` is not a `BinaryOperator`<WordCounter>`. I would have assumed you'd have another error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context). If you were to understand the different in the signature of BinaryOperator and BiFunction.

Answer (score 3):

A `BinaryOperator<T>` is equivalent to a `BiFunction<T, T, T>`. In your case it would need to take two `WordCounter` instances and return a `WordCounter` instance. `WordCounter::combine` would be valid but not `WordCounter::accumulate`.

The second `reduce` method doesn't require both input types to be the same. That means that `WordCounter::accumulate` is resolved to a `BiFunction<WordCounter, Character, WordCounter>` which is allowed - `U` is `WordCounter` and `T` is `Character`.